# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9200/test12/test3/_search?pretty

Tags: jquery, json, cors

I have an autocomplete jquery function with ElasticSearch. I'm getting the following error when typing the first letter in.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9200/test12/test3/_search?pretty. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Here is the code

```
$(function () {
    $("#keyword").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                 url: "http://localhost:9200/test12/test3/_search?pretty",
                data: "q=firstname:" + request.term +"*" , 
                dataType: "json", 
                type: "POST", 
                headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  'http://localhost'
            },
                crossDomain: true,    
                jsonpCallback:"callback", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data); 
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {


                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('error'+ response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('failure'+response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("[id$=keyword]").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

I also tried `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*'` it didn't work.

When I try `jsonp` instead of `json`, I get

> syntax error (which is normal, since my code expects json not jsonp stuff)

on the SERVER: I did,

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin$
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

STILL did not solve the problem

Comment: The `Access-Control-*` headers are **response** headers. They need to come from the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: Enable cross origin support on your SERVER.  The browser will not allow a cross origin request unless the server allows it.

Comment: tried that!!Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
 on /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 5):

Use a browser addon that allows the user to enable CORS everywhere by altering http responses.

Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf/

Safari: No need to install any add-on, just go to Develop > Disable Cross-origin Restrictions. If you don't have the Develop menu in Safari, follow this instructions:

Comment: So you tell all your visitors they have to install something on their browser?  That's not an answer!

Comment: @MC9000 The context of this question (and of my answer) is testing in a local machine, most probably for development purposes. Thus, in this particular context my answer is a suggestion based on what I did to solve my local development environment. This has nothing to do on what and how I deploy to production environments, which is out of the scope of this question. That said, you are most welcome to propose your own answer... that's the whole idea of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This solution sounded promising, but did not solve the issue for me. I am still getting the same errors on the console. I will get back to this post if I find a solution elsewhere.

Comment: Worked for me, for testing at least.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, the solution suggested is only for testing purposes. You could also setup a proxy server. In any case, production environments need another setup altogether.